# Is there a way to display HTML page that is not dependent on IE?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

My client WPF application needs to display an HTML page. I understand that the webbrowser control uses the version of IE that is installed on the box.

Is there a control to render HTML that can be totally embedded into my application so that it is not dependent on the version of IE, that the user has installed?

What would happed if a user is using IE6?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use [WebKit .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) instead. It allows you to embed a WebKit browser in your .NET application without having to have extra software installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [geckofx](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) if you would rather go the Mozilla Gecko route.